# onChange value not visible?

Tags: reactjs, expo

I'm, learning about onChange and I want to display the text that I write into the "testInput" to be shown as currentInput text - what am I doing wrong here?

```
const Start = () => {

const [Input, setInput] = useState("")

function handleChange(event) {
    setInput(event.target.value)
}


return (
<View style= {styles.mainContainer}>
    <Header/>

    <Text style={{fontSize: 30}}>This is:{Input}</Text>

    <TextInput 
    style={styles.goalInput} 
    title="Add goal"
    value={Input}
    onChange={handleChange}/>

</View>  
)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be TextInput instead of TestInput and also you are missing value attribute. Hope so It will help you.

```
<TextInput title="Add Test"
    onChange={(e) => {setCurrentInput (e.target.value)}}
value={currentInput} />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the TestInput is a component that includes a textinput hehe, I tried the value but it still isn't working :(

Comment: If it is a component then you are just passing the prop in your component.  Now you you have to go to the TestInput component and add 
onChange={props.onChange} and value={props.value} in TextInput.

Comment: I tried this but its not working, when I put "console.log(event.target.value)" and write in textinput it just logs out "undefined" instead of the letters i'm typing in, does that say anything to you?

Comment: Can you please share code of TestInput component so I can help to understand the issue.

Comment: I updated the code in the top, please check it out! made it into a textinput to simplify the code without the custom component

Comment: please use onChangeText instead of onChange and also 
function handleChange(text) {
    console.log(text);
}

Comment: Yes that made the console log display the letters typed in :D thank you, but still cant get them to display using setInput instead of console.log :/

Comment: can you please change spelling for Input (state). May It resolved our issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
   <TestInput title="Add Test"
        onChange={(e) => {setCurrentInput (e.target.value)}}
    value={currentInput}
    />
```

You have to add the value prop aswell to the Input that's how it will be updated in the input by passing value as the text you are upadting in your case you are setting state of currentInput, so value={currentInput}

Comment: Ah okay thank you, I added the value but the text still isn't showing up :/ could there be something else I missed?

Comment: No, adding value to TestInput should be enough, if you have made TestInput your custom component make sure to add value and onChange prop in TestInput component aswell.

Comment: I tried this but its not working, when I put "console.log(event.target.value)" and write in textinput it just logs out "undefined" instead of the letters i'm typing in, does that say anything to you?

Comment: The updated code should work now, it's working now right?